# Reading data from json array

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

My json format is like -

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "مرحبا"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

i want to read translated text value without using json.net . 
but it always returns null value.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            nameList myNames = ser.Deserialize<nameList>(json);
```

Comment: what does nameList look like

Comment: public class nameList
        {
            public name[] Translator { get; set; }
        }

Comment: why not use newtonsoft.json?

Comment: Does it make things more easy, actually i haven't used it.

Comment: It's used exactly for that. It'll convert your json text into an C# Object which  is waaaaay easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public class nameList { public name[] Translator { get; set; } }

That's an incorrect class to map the Json to.

---

Try these classes to deserialize the Json and it will work perfectly fine:

```
public class Translation
{
    public string translatedText { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Translation> translations { get; set; }
}

public class nameList
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Example reaching for the `translatedText` property:

```
var text = myNames.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

Comment: @AnoopMishra you should mark the answer as accepted in case it was ;-) and you're welcome :-)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the `nameList` class (from the comments) that this JSON is being converted into, and the sample JSON provided, the reason that the returned value is null is down to the `Deserialize` method not being able to map to the class.

From the provided information, I've recreated the necessary classes.

```
class nameList {
    public name[] Translator { get; set; }
}

class name {
    public string TranslatedText { get; set; }
}
```

I've then attempted to parse the provided JSON into those classes using the following

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
// The json data, in one line
string json = "{\"data\":{\"translations\":[{\"translatedText\": \"مرحبا\"}]}}";

// Convert back into object similar to described
nameList myNames = serializer.Deserialize<nameList>(json);

try {
    // Attempt to access
    Console.WriteLine(myNames.Translator[0]);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail:" + ex.Message);
}
```

On execution, the following was output to the console.

```
Fail: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Meaning that the return value was null.

As previously stated, this is due to the `Deserialize` method not being able to map to the class. (though it is strange that an `InvalidOperationException` didn't trigger) So lets see what JSON can be mapped by converting an instance of `nameList`.

```
// Manually created object
nameList myNames = new nameList() {
    Translator = new name[] {
        new name() { TranslatedText = "مرحبا" }
    }
};

// Convert to JSON
string json = serializer.Serialize(myNames);
Console.WriteLine("JSON:\n" + json);
```

On execution, the following was output.

```
JSON:
{"Translator":[{"TranslatedText":"?????"}]}
```

Aside from the obvious fact that the VSCode debug console doesn't support that language, we are faced with some very different JSON.

So lets dissect this...

```
{ "Translator": [
        {
            "TranslatedText": "مرحبا"
        }
    ]
}
```

1. There is only 2 named fields, compared to 3 in the sample JSON.
2. The 2 named fields match the properties in the classes, I believe this is mandatory for the `JavaScriptSerializer` class in order for it to map the values correctly. (Other libraries such as JSON.net have ways around this restriction.)

Hopefully this has helped.